# Unable to install Nvidia Drivers for Ubuntu - No release file in repo?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, cuda

Sorry, quite new to Ubuntu and I know there are questions on nvidia drivers, but none seem to answer my specific problem - whenever I call `sudo apt-get update`, my computer attempts to install Nvidia drives from a repo that 'does not have a release file', causing it to fail. I attempted to follow the tutorial for cuda on the Nvidia page (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal). Anyone have some ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't told us the release of Ubuntu you are using, and the actual error message (which has a URL we can use to ensure you release is supported).  It's possibly your release of Ubuntu is not supported by that repo (we can't know as we know neither) or it's something else - but we need more detail to check for you.  Look at the `apt-get update` output for what you need to solve it.

Comment: You are right, I think the problem came down to that (was using 18.04, which supports installing drivers via Software Update). I think I need to reinstall my OS because I have now messed it up beyond repair, but I have a better idea of how to restart. Thanks!